# Как правильно отправить данные через ajax в telegram

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, telegram

Сделал опросник для сайта на JS. JS отрабатывает хорошо, но не получается правильно передать данные через ajax в телеграм

Код HTML опросника

```
<div class="scene">
                      
                        <div class="qwestion qwestion-1" style='background: white;'>
                            <span class="qwestion__number">qwestion</span>
                            <h2 class="qwestion__heading">textqwestion</h2>
                            <div class="qwestion__selects-wrapper">
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-1" data-cost="20" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-1" id="qwestion-1-1"  checked>
                                    <label for="qwestion-1-1" class="qwestion__input-label">seck1</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-1" data-cost="10" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-1" id="qwestion-1-2" >
                                    <label for="qwestion-1-2" class="qwestion__input-label">seck2</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-1" data-cost="10" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-1" id="qwestion-1-3" >
                                    <label for="qwestion-1-3" class="qwestion__input-label">seck3</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-1" data-cost="0" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-1" id="qwestion-1-4" >
                                    <label for="qwestion-1-4" class="qwestion__input-label">seck4</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="qwestion qwestion-3"  style='background: white;'>
                            <span class="qwestion__number">qwestion2</span>
                            <h2 class="qwestion__heading">textqwestion</h2>
                            <div class="qwestion__selects-wrapper">
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-3" data-cost="20" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-3" id="qwestion-3-1"  checked>
                                    <label for="qwestion-3-1" class="qwestion__input-label">seck1</label>
                                </div>
    
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-3" data-cost="20" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-3" id="qwestion-3-2" >
                                    <label for="qwestion-3-2" class="qwestion__input-label">seck2</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-3" data-cost="10" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-3" id="qwestion-3-3">
                                    <label for="qwestion-3-3" class="qwestion__input-label">seck2</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-3" data-cost="0" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-3" id="qwestion-3-4" >
                                    <label for="qwestion-3-4" class="qwestion__input-label">seck3</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-3" data-cost="10" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-3 qwestion-3-custom-choose other" id="qwestion-3-5" value="иное">
                                    <label for="qwestion-3-5" class="qwestion__input-label other">seck4</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="qwestion-3-custom qwestion-input" id="qwestion-3-custom" name="qwestion-3-custom" style="display: none;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="qwestion qwestion-4"  style='background: white;'>
                            <span class="qwestion__number">qwestion3</span>
                            <h2 class="qwestion__heading">textqwestion</h2>
                            <div class="qwestion__selects-wrapper">
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-4" data-cost="30" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-4" id="qwestion-4-1"  checked>
                                    <label for="qwestion-4-1" class="qwestion__input-label">seck1</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-4" data-cost="20" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-4" id="qwestion-4-2">
                                    <label for="qwestion-4-2" class="qwestion__input-label">seck2</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-4" data-cost="0" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-4" id="qwestion-4-3" >
                                    <label for="qwestion-4-3" class="qwestion__input-label">seck3</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-4" data-cost="10" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-4" id="qwestion-4-4" >
                                    <label for="qwestion-4-4" class="qwestion__input-label">seck4</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-4" data-cost="10" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-4" id="qwestion-4-5" >
                                    <label for="qwestion-4-5" class="qwestion__input-label">seck5</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-4" data-cost="10" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-4" id="qwestion-4-6" >
                                    <label for="qwestion-4-6" class="qwestion__input-label">seck6</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="qwestion qwestion-5"  style='background: white;'>
                            <span class="qwestion__number">qwestion4</span>
                            <h2 class="qwestion__heading">textqwestion</h2>
                            <div class="qwestion__selects-wrapper">
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-5" data-cost="0" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-5" id="qwestion-5-1"  checked>
                                    <label for="qwestion-5-1" class="qwestion__input-label">seck1</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-5" data-cost="20" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-5" id="qwestion-5-2" >
                                    <label for="qwestion-5-2" class="qwestion__input-label">seck2</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-5" data-cost="20" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-5" id="qwestion-5-3" >
                                    <label for="qwestion-5-3" class="qwestion__input-label">seck3</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-5" data-cost="20" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-5" id="qwestion-5-4" >
                                    <label for="qwestion-5-4" class="qwestion__input-label">seck4</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="qwestion qwestion-6"  style='background: white;'>
                            <span class="qwestion__number">qwestion5</span><br>
                            <h2 class="qwestion__heading">textqwestion</h2>
                            <div class="qwestion__selects-wrapper">
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-6" data-cost="0" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-6" id="qwestion-6-1"  checked>
                                    <label for="qwestion-6-1" class="qwestion__input-label">seck1</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-6" data-cost="20" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-6" id="qwestion-6-2" >
                                    <label for="qwestion-6-2" class="qwestion__input-label">seck2</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-5" data-cost="20" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-5" id="qwestion-6-3" >
                                    <label for="qwestion-6-3" class="qwestion__input-label">seck3</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="qwestion__selects-item">
                                    <input type="radio" name="qwestion-6" data-cost="20" class="qwestion__input-radio qwestion-6" id="qwestion-6-4" >
                                    <label for="qwestion-6-4" class="qwestion__input-label">seck4</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                                           <div class="qwestion qwestion-8"  style='background: #fff179;'>
                            <span class="qwestion__number">qwestion6</span>
               
                           
                            <form action="#" method="post" id="final-qwestion" class="final-qwestion">
    
    <h3><font color="red"><b>textqwestion</b></font></h3>
    
                               <input type="text" name="gorod" placeholder="sity" class="qwestion-input" id="qwestion__gorod-input" required> 
                                
                                
                                <input type="text" name="tel2" placeholder="phone" class="qwestion-input" id="qwestion__tel-input" required>
                                <div>
                                         
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" form="final-qwestion" id="final-qwestion__btn" class="btn red-btn final-qwestion__btn">resuld</button>
                                
                                
                                     
                                <input type="checkbox" class="question-data-checkbox" id="question-data-checkbox" checked>
                               
                               
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="qwestion__buttons-wrap">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qwestion__buttons qwestion__prev-btn">prev</a>
                            
    
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn red-btn qwestion__buttons qwestion__next-btn">Confim</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

JavaScript

function compileForm() {
// take answers

```
    var answerInput1 = $('.qwestion-1:checked'),
        answerInput2 = $('.qwestion-2:checked'),
        answerInput3 = $('.qwestion-3:checked'),
        answerInput4 = $('.qwestion-4:checked'),
        answerInput5 = $('.qwestion-5:checked');
    answerInput3Custom = $('#qwestion-3-custom');

    scoreSum = answerInput1.data('cost') + answerInput2.data('cost') + answerInput3.data('cost') + answerInput4.data('cost') + answerInput5.data('cost');

    var answer1 = answerInput1.val(),
        answer2 = answerInput2.val(),
        answer3 = answerInput3.val(),
        answer4 = answerInput4.val(),
        answer5 = answerInput5.val();

    if (answerInput3.hasClass('qwestion-3-custom-choose')) {
        console.log('another');
        answer3 += ' - ' + answerInput3Custom.val();
    }

    // put unswers to inputs
    var sendInp1 = $('#answer-1').val(answer1),
        sendInp2 = $('#answer-2').val(answer2),
        sendInp3 = $('#answer-3').val(answer3),
        sendInp4 = $('#answer-4').val(answer4),
        sendInp5 = $('#answer-5').val(answer5);
    sendInp6 = $('#answer-6').val(scoreSum);

};
$('#final-qwestion__btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var answers = [];
    $('.qwestion').each(function(index, el) {
        var number = index + 1;
        if (index > 4) {
            answers.push(number + ') Номер телефона —— ' + $(this).find('#qwestion__tel-input').val() + '')
                answers.push(number + ') Город : —— ' + $(this).find('#qwestion__gorod-input').val() + '')
        } else if (index == 2) {
            if ($(this).find('input:checked').hasClass('other')) {
                answers.push(number + ') ' + $(this).find('.qwestion__heading').text() + ' —— ' + $(this).find('#qwestion-3-custom').val() + '')
            } else {
                answers.push(number + ') ' + $(this).find('.qwestion__heading').text() + ' —— ' + $(this).find('input:checked').val() + '')

            }
        } else {
            answers.push(number + ') ' + $(this).find('.qwestion__heading').text() + ' —— ' + $(this).find('input:checked').val() + '')
        }

    });
    if (!$('#qwestion__tel-input').val()) {
        $('#qwestion__tel-input').css('box-shadow', '0 0 20px 0px #990033');
    } else {
        $('#qwestion__tel-input').css('box-shadow', 'none');
        answers = answers.join('\n')
        console.log(answers);
        $.ajax({
                url: 'send/send.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    postData: answers
                },
                success: function(resultData){
      alert("Save Complete");
  }
            })
    }
    

});
```

});

PHP

```
  <?php
    if (isset($_POST['qwestion-1'])) {
          $qwestionq = strip_tags($_POST['qwestion-1']);
          $qwestionqFieldset = "<b>qwestion1:</b> ";
        }
    if (isset($_POST['qwestion-3'])) {
          $qwestiona = strip_tags($_POST['qwestion-3']);
          $qwestionaFieldset = "<b>qwestion2:</b>";
        }
    if (isset($_POST['qwestion-4'])) {
          $qwestioz = strip_tags($_POST['qwestion-4']);
          $qwestionzFieldset = "<b>qwestion3:</b> ";
        }
    if (isset($_POST['qwestion-5'])) {
         $qwestionw = strip_tags($_POST['qwestion-5']);
          $qwestionwFieldset = "<b>qwestion4:</b> ";
        }
    if (isset($_POST['qwestion-6'])) {
          $qwestions = strip_tags($_POST['qwestion-6']);
          $qwestionsFieldset = "<b>qwestion5:</b> ";
        }    
    if (isset($_POST['gorod'])) {
          $gorod = strip_tags($_POST['gorod']);
          $gorodFieldset = "<b>qwestion6:</b> ";
        } 
    if (isset($_POST['tel2'])) {
          $tel = strip_tags($_POST['tel2']);
          $telFieldset = "<b>qwestion7:</b> ";
        }     
    
    $token = "";
    
        $chat_id_scr = "";
    $txt = rawurlencode($txt);
    $arr = array(
      $qwestionqFieldset => $qwestionq,
      $qwestionaFieldset => $qwestiona,
      $qwestionzFieldset => $qwestionz,
      $qwestionwFieldset => $qwestionw,
      $qwestionwFieldset => $qwestions,
      $gorodFieldset => $gorod,
      $telFieldset => $tel,
    );
    
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
      $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b>".$value."%0A";
    };
    
    $sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id_scr}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");
```

Comment: Таааак, клево что скинули код. А ошибка то в чем?)

Comment: [03-May-2021 13:15:34 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  fopen(https://api.telegram.org/bot1725142288:AAENKfIcuawCcv35r9LCYEnb8e5_DUy1x38/sendMessage?chat_id=488753986&amp;parse_mode=html&amp;text=&lt;b&gt;&lt;/b&gt;%0A): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
 in D:\OpenServer\domains\opros.lock\send\send.php on line 22

Comment: Либо я не правильно передаю данные, либо еще что

Comment: добавьте ошибку в вопрос, что бы всем видно было, пожалуйста)

Comment: если задать в php статичные объекты( а не принимать через post) т овсе ок

Comment: а 22 строка на что указывает?

Comment: token и chat_id_scr передаешь правильно?

Comment: да. Правильно. Пробовал $txt = rawurlencode($txt); думаю что тут косяк но нет.

Comment: Если же переделать $qwestionq = "<b>qwestion7:</b> "; и т.д то все отправляется

Comment: а что сейчас в переменной $qwestionq ?

Comment: Должны быть выбранные данные с опроса.

Comment: console.log(answers); Выводит все данные из массива answers правильно. Но получается передать я их не могу правильно. И как правильно - проблема

Comment: тебя спросили - что сейчас в переменной $qwestionq  - ?

Comment: Должны быть данные с поля strip_tags($_POST['qwestion-1']);